# bmi calculator in java web application

Tags: java, jsp, submit

I need to  calculate the bmi in java
I have this code so far

input_page.jsp

```
<form action="calc_bmi.jsp" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>height:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="height" size="35" maxlength="6" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>weight:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="weight" size="35" maxlength="6" ></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2"><input type="button" onclick="formReset()" value="reset">
<input type="submit" value="submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>   
</form>
```

calc_bmi.jsp

```
<%
String wt=request.getParameter("weight");
String ht=request.getParameter("height");

double weight=Integer.parseInt(wt);
double height=Integer.parseInt(ht);

double w=weight;
double h=height*height;
double bmi = w/h;
out.println("BMI of weight "+weight+" and height "+height+" is: "+bmi);
%>
```

How I could do it so to accept decimals from weight and height fields?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Its simple,

Instead of `Integer` class use `Double`

like :

`double weight=Double.parseDouble(wt);`

Also I advice you to do some validation with java script before submitting the form, or while parsing the data on server side, otherwise it can throw `NumberFormatException`